# MS Access - Run a query displaying one result per user

Tags: ms-access-2010

I've got a database that I'm tying into our access control system. I'm trying to create a report showing the user's first entry and last exit from the building. I've put a query together which hows me the right single result for one user, but I want to automate this to run through a list of users.

The query for grabbing the first entry for one user (as it is currently) is as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 AccessLog.ID, AccessLog.Date, First(AccessLog.Time) AS FirstOfTime, AccessLog.User, AccessLog.Details, AccessLog.Event, AccessLog.Department, AccessLog.Where
FROM AccessLog
GROUP BY AccessLog.ID, AccessLog.Date, AccessLog.User, AccessLog.Details, AccessLog.Event, AccessLog.Department, AccessLog.Where
HAVING (((AccessLog.Date)=#DATE#) AND ((AccessLog.User)="USERNAME") AND ((AccessLog.Where)="Front Door (In)"))
ORDER BY First(AccessLog.Time);
```

I have a separate table of all the usernames, would it be possible to do a run-as for this?

Basically I'm a complete Access n00b, in the past I'd have done this with PHP and a recurring function but this should be fairly easy to achieve within Access, shouldn't it? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean *do a run-as*?  You can add a parameter to the query, or you can group by user and then filter in your form, report, etc?

Comment: Think I worded that badly after a long day. I mean running the query for each value of USERNAME in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the arrival times for all users by date with the following query. Save the query definition under the name "ArriveTimes":

```
SELECT AccessLog.Date, AccessLog.User, Min(AccessLog.Time) AS ArriveTime
FROM AccessLog
WHERE (((AccessLog.Where)="Front Door (In)"))
GROUP BY AccessLog.Date, AccessLog.User;
```

Similarly, you can get the departure times with a similar query saved as "DepartTimes":

```
SELECT AccessLog.Date, AccessLog.User, Max(AccessLog.Time) AS DepartTime
FROM AccessLog
WHERE (((AccessLog.Where)="Front Door (Out)"))
GROUP BY AccessLog.Date, AccessLog.User;
```

Then you can join the [ArriveTimes] and the [DepartTimes] queries together (JOIN on [Date] and [User]) and pull the other details by joining on two instances of the [AccessLog] table (JOIN on [Date], [User], and [Time]):

```
SELECT ArriveTimes.Date, ArriveTimes.User, 
    ArriveTimes.ArriveTime, AccessLog_A.Details AS ArriveDetails, 
    DepartTimes.DepartTime, AccessLog_D.Details AS DepartDetails
FROM 
    (AccessLog AS AccessLog_A INNER JOIN 
        (ArriveTimes INNER JOIN DepartTimes 
            ON (ArriveTimes.User = DepartTimes.User) 
                AND (ArriveTimes.Date = DepartTimes.Date)
        ) 
        ON (ArriveTimes.ArriveTime = AccessLog_A.Time) 
            AND (AccessLog_A.User = ArriveTimes.User) 
            AND (AccessLog_A.Date = ArriveTimes.Date)
    ) 
    INNER JOIN AccessLog AS AccessLog_D 
        ON (DepartTimes.DepartTime = AccessLog_D.Time) 
            AND (DepartTimes.User = AccessLog_D.User) 
            AND (DepartTimes.Date = AccessLog_D.Date);
```